# How to solve this issues in magento for update Currency Rate?

Tags: magento-1.9

Currency update warnings:

WARNING: Cannot retrieve rate from http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&to={{CURRENCY_TO}}

I got this message in my email during cron job call. Please help me for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are calling does not work anymore.

You need to edit the file `app/code/local/Payserv/GoogleFinance/Model/Google.php` (or the one you are using) and replace

```
https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&to={{CURRENCY_TO}}
```

with

```
https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&to={{CURRENCY_TO}}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now. 
First, it was not working because the compiler is enabled so I did change in this file Payserv_GoogleFinance_Model_Google.php and this file is in /public_html/includes/src folder.